# Oracle to Postgres Conversion Regexp Concept

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Can someone please let me know how to convert the below oracle source code in a stored procedure to `Postgresql`

```
CURSOR DATA_PKG (iPKG varchar2)IS
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(iPKG, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) Data_PKG FROM dual
connect BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(iPKG, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
CURSOR LEC_PKG (iPKG varchar2) IS
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(iPKG, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) LEC_Pkg FROM dual
connect BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(iPKG, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

My Postgres code is as follows,

```
c3 CURSOR (ipkg TEXT) FOR
    WITH RECURSIVE t (pkg)
    AS (SELECT
        aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS data_pkg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, t.level + 1)
        FROM t
        WHERE aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, level + 1) IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT
        data_pkg
        FROM t;
    c4 CURSOR (ipkg TEXT) FOR
    WITH RECURSIVE t2 (pkg)
    AS (SELECT
        aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS lec_pkg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, t2.level + 1)
        FROM t2
        WHERE aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, level + 1) IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT
        lec_pkg
        FROM t2;
```

But when I'm executing this function in `Postgresql` its throwing an error as below,

```
ERROR:  column t.level does not exist LINE 6: ...   aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, t.level + ...
                                                             ^ QUERY:  WITH RECURSIVE t (pkg)
    AS (SELECT
        aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS data_pkg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, t.level + 1)
        FROM t
        WHERE aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr(ipkg, '[^,]+', 1, level + 1) IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT
        data_pkg
        FROM t CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "pop_bus_bundle$populate_bundle_names"() line 60 at FOR over cursor SQL state: 42703
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's `aws_oracle_ext.regexp_substr` ? Is it some kind of wrapper API of that is doing the conversion?

Why not directly use the Postgres equivalent that splits comma separated string into rows? It seems ultimately that's what your select statements in source code are doing.

```
select  regexp_split_to_table(iPKG,',');
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=03fac9aefe79abf0cafa3409f22228f9)

Comment: Really a Great Answer, Thanks for looking into this Kaushik, it worked absolutely Great!